# vimrc settings for user dont work for root

Tags: vim

I have modified the .vimrc file in my user. The settings dont work when i switch to superuser. 
When i check the contents of the file (using vim editor) i can see the mapped keystrokes of newlines 
(with all the text extending on the rightside beyond screen on same line), but when i check the contents of .vimrc as root, i see all the text in the same window screen one below the other (this may be a very stupid difference, but that is the only difference i noticed. all the data in the file is same).

i am unable to understand what is wrong and how can i correct it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

root is a user too, when you start vim with root, vim load the `root's Home/.vimrc` usually it is `/root/.vimrc`

You can cp or ln -s your user's vimrc to `/root` if this is a personal desktop machine.

I hope I understood your problem.

Comment: i deleted the roots .vimrc (my bad). now i want to copy the .vimrc of user to .vimrc of root and dont know how to do it. (i searched on web but didnt find valuable article)

Comment: login as root, then `cp /home/user/.vimrc /root/.vimrc` note that, the `/home/user` could be different, depends on your mount setting. It is the `$HOME` of your user. @D.7

Answer (score 4):

You did not state a precise question, so for the sake of completeness :
If what you want is being able to modify files as root using your user's vim and .vimrc, you can do

```
sudo -e /path/to/your/file
```

sudo will use the editor configured in `$EDITOR` as the current user, to edit a temporary copy of the file that will get copied over when you write the file.

The caveat is that you will not be able to have any edition history between sessions. For example, if you modify `/etc/group` once, save the changes and quit, and then reopen the file again, you will not be able to undo the modification you did at first.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian GNU/Linux there is also a shared configuration file in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`.  (Actually this is a soft link to `/etc/vim/vimrc`.)  See the bottom of the man page on vim.

Answer (score 1):

For Neovim users, you can do what comes next:

1. If your root user settings for neovim are important, make a
   backup for those dotfiles.
2. Create a symbolic link from your default user to **/root/.config** directory.

   sudo mv /root/.config/nvim /root/.config/nvim.bkp; sudo ln -s $HOME/.config/nvim /root/.config/

> Be aware that some plugins may need some files that are not under
> **.config/nvim** directory.